# Vectorize some subtle function to speed up the performance

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, vectorization, lmfit

I have an array `Tmat(m,n)` which all elements should be optimized in the same function `myfunc(t)`. So I define the `myfunc(t)` in scipy.optimize or lmfit，and use np.vectorize or loops to achieve the goal. Some toy codes like this, `Amat` is some matrix with shape `(m,n)`, `x0` is some given constant

```
def myfunc(a,x):
    def loss(pars, x):
        vals = pars.valuesdict()
        t = vals['t']
        return (x-t)**2

    pars=lmfit.Parameters()
    pars.add('t',value=1.0)
    out=lmfit.minimize(loss,pars,args=(x,))
    return out.params['t'].value

# Using np.vectorize
vec_myfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc, excluded=['param'], signature='(),(m,n)->()')
tmat=vec_myfunc(Amat,x0)
# Using loops
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
             tmat[i,j]=myfunc(Amat[i,j],x0)
```

It is very very slow. [The document of numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) said "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance". So it does not really vectorizing the function. Since tmat[i,j] with different i,j do not interact during the optimization, it should be able to speeded up by vectorization or parallelization. How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: what about multiprocessing library?

Comment: Proposing multiprocessing module ( no matter whether using it directly or indirectly via joblib ) **unless understanding the Amdahl Law and accounting and having all the add-on costs safely adjusted** is a sure road to a worse performance. For details read about the add-on costs in https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3 and measure how many [us] your O/S spends on instantiating another full-scale process ( Win-class O/S in addition copy the whole python interpreter's process RAM ( no fork, or fork-server methods avoiding full-copies of RAM available for Win-class O/S as of 2019/4Q )

Comment: Using multiprocessing or simply breaking up the work in separate processes is almost certainly what you here.  Optimization codes with `lmfit` or `scipy.optimize` are generally inherently single-core procedures, not easily parallelized.  But you can do each of your NxM fits separately, each in their own process.  Yes, creating a process uses resources, but that is necessary when the problem is not easily parallelized and not I/O bound.  Least-squares minimization is neither.

Comment: `np.vectorize` does allow you to apply a scalar function to all elements of an array (or better yet several broadcasted arrays).  In that sense it really does 'vectorize'.  What it does not do is compile your function and iterate in fast C code.

Comment: `np.vectorize` with signature is even slower than its regular version (which uses `np.frompyfunc`).  But directly using `np.frompyfunc` is even faster, sometimes 2x better than an explicit loop.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your use of `vectorize`.  The `excluded` argument doesn't do anything since there's no `param` variable.  If `x0` is a constant, it doesn't need to be part of the `vectorize` broadcasting.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `lmfit`, but know from other SO questions, that applying `scipy.optimize.minimize` to different 'conditions' (either different `x0` or `args`) has to be done iteratively.  That is, each parameter-set has to be run separately.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, `lmfit` and `scipy.optimize.minimize` use iterative procedures, internal calling of user-level functions, and store the iteration results to arrive at a solution. 
These methods do not lend themselves to easy parallelization.   People have tried.  Amdahl's law applies in the sense that it gives "maximum possible improvement".  The minimum possible improvement is None, or even < 1.